# How can I make a turtle randomly choose one of two conditions?

Tags: netlogo

I have the code :

```
             if color of patch-here = blue [set heading towards one-of      patches in-radius 180 with pcolor = grey ( do that or ) die ]
```

What I want to be able to do is to allow each turtle to randomly select one of the two options. I appreciate I could assign each command a number and then use a random number generator to select one of the two commands, but I am wondering whether there is a combination of commands that I could use to replace ( do that or ).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Roll a dice, if dice < 5, do something, else do the other thing. Example:

```
if pcolor = blue [
  let dice random 10 
  ifelse dice < 5 [
     set heading towards one-of patches in-radius 180 with pcolor = grey]
     [die]
]
```

Comment: you can also use `random-float 1 < p` where p is the proportion that you want to go to the first condition. eg `ifelse random-float 1 < 0.4 [code for option1] [code for option2]` will have option 1 chosen 40% of the time.